# Applicable Design pattern

Tags: java, jsf, design-patterns

I have this working hierarchy already and the program runs as expected.  Basically I have abstracted everything in a Base class and all other subclass adding their own methods.

```
abstract Class Base{
}

class A extends Base{
    //new methods
}

class B extends Base{
    //new methods
}
```

everything looks good until later (errr...new requirements) I realize I need to have a new class (lets call this class C) that extends both
class A and B.  Now, in java its not possible to extend two concrete class.

```
class C extends A, B{
    //new methods
}
```

I need both of the methods and variables in class A and class B but I dont know how to do this?
Any hints on how do I do this change?
I am not that good in design pattern so i thought of asking it here.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
This is actually a JSF Managed Bean wherein I abstracted everything in a Base Managed Bean and all other subclass overriding/adding their own implementations on top of the base managed bean.
There is just a new requirement that was added wherein I needed the functionality of both subclasses (A and B) into a new subclass (C)

Comment: It's tricky to say without more details of what the classes do, but it sounds like you would be better off with a component based design.

Comment: You need the methods, but is the relationship `C is a A and B` necessary ? You can use composition, but your post needs more info to know if this is appropriate.

Comment: Yeh consider composition and have `C` contain instances of `A` and `B`.

Comment: may be interface can help you. Create an interface with all methods of A and B and implement these methods in the class C.

Comment: Hi, I have updated it accordingly to give it some context.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Comment: @Deepak... yes I need it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactor your code and make `A` and `B` and `Base` interfaces instead of classes and use interface inheritance instead of implementation inheritance.
Then you can implement both `A` and `B` (this is how multiple inheritance is supported in `Java`)

Comment: In the question @Mark Estrada has mentioned "I need both of the methods and variables in class A and class B" So, I guess he cant change `A` and `B` to interfaces because they seem to  have member variables.

Comment: @codeMan:Member variables are not an issue. He just need to redesign his code properly.

Comment: And he would have to reimplement all of the methods instead of using existing code then.

Comment: So, If I make A, B and Base as interfaces then it means I need to add new concrete class to implement them?  is this correct?  I have no qualms about refactoring actually but I just need to know the best and possible way of solving this problem.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The best way to design is using *interfaces*. Avoid implementation inheritance as much as possible as it tightly couples your code and make it affected by changes (you already are seeing the problems). Use implementation inheritance sparingly

Answer (score 3):

Either use composition or use inner class.

```
class C extends A {
   B b = ... // this is one option

   class D extends B {
     // this is another option 
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should create all the classes A, B and Base as interfaces, but as you have mentioned that above design was already implemented I am assuming that this is not an option now.

The other solution is to create an instance of type A or/ and B in the class C (composition).

```
Class C{
A a=new A();
B b=new B();
}
```

You can also use a mixed approach using both inheritance and composition like extend A and create instance of B.

Answer (score 1):

Lets `C` contain `A` and `B` but also make it `extend Base` then delegate so you don't have to duplicate anything.

```
class C extends Base
{
   A a = new A();
   B b = new B();

   // Now delegate any implemented methods from Base to A and B

   @Override
   public void anAbstractMethod()
   {
      a.anAbstractMethod();
      b.anAbstractMethod();
   }
}
```